# NLog get messages in C#

Tags: c#, nlog

I am recently using Nlog in an ASP.Net project for a client with good success. I need to connect to an existing application that has its own event log management and provide them with a copy of my log information.

Is there any way to get the strings that I provided to Nlog using any of the log functions?

Example:

```
logger.Info("My info");
logger.Debug("My debug");
logger.Error("My error");
logger.Warn("My warn");
List<string> messages = logger.getStrings() <-- this is what I need
```

How I can get strings "My info", "My debug", "My error" and "My warn" as an array or List<>?

Comment: Are your logs written to a database?  That would be the easiest way of getting log data from one application in another.  You can also use a `MemoryAppender` and get its internal buffer.

Comment: @amy `MemoryAppender`? Sounds like log4net?

Comment: @Julian Oops, I was channeling my inner NLog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [MemoryTarget](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Memory-target) for it:

nlog.config:

```xml
<nlog internalLogFile="c:\tempp\nlog-internal.log" internalLogLevel="Info">
    <targets>
        <target xsi:type="Memory" name="target1" layout="${message}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" writeTo="target1" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

C#:

```cs
var target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<MemoryTarget>("target1");
IList<string> messages = target.Logs;
```

The messages are `strings`, rendered from the `layout` attribute in nlog.config

[API docs for MemoryTarget](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.4.0/html/T_NLog_Targets_MemoryTarget.htm)

If you need to write them to another component, I would recommend to create a [custom target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target)

Comment: Thanks, this is what i needed. Is there any way to get also the level together with the message?

Comment: Sure, change the layout attribute and add `${level}`

Comment: Notice that NLog ver. 4.6 introduces the property `MaxLogsCount`. Can be useful if wanting to avoid out-of-memory situations.